# What are my alternatives for managing RabbitMQ channel changes as a part of CD process

Tags: continuous-integration, rabbitmq, continuous-deployment

I am looking for alternatives for managing my RabbitMQ setup, same as i manage my RDBMS with liquibase/flyway or mongo with mongeez.

After looking around a bit I havent found any resources on it as much (Which gets me thinking on how companies actually do it).

I read thread that talked about each component creating the channels that it needs to its either there or it will be created in runtime when needed.

Other then that i haven't found any mention of a request like mine, am i looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: What flavour of CD are you using? As different approaches can support different solutions.

Comment: its an interesting question, For the purpose of this question lets assume that its a vagrant machine with rabbitMQ on it, but in the future i would like it to integrate with my Jenkins CI managment

Answer (score 0):

We manage it the following way. It's not a clean straight forward solution, but it works.

1. Installation, update and base-configuration of RabbitMQ is done via an ansible role.
2. Creation, update and deletion of virtual hosts, users and access permissions is done via a second ansible role
3. Management, i.e. create, update and delete of queues and exchanges is done from within the application

With this setup we were able to provide a multi tenant configuration and efficiently manage several installations in several stages.